# For a single Application Pool, how many Worker Processes should be allowed to run?

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7.5

[image]

Honestly I don't know the effect of increasing or decreasing the number of worker processes.

For a single Application Pool, how many Worker Processes should be allowed to run?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I follow, and I'm looking to find it in the documentation, that you should not run more worker processes then twice the number of processor cores.

- In a single core system : 2
- In a dual core system : 4
- etc.

Comment: I'm searching now. We had a large performance problem with a large web farm a few months ago and spent a great deal of time researching every setting...

Comment: Are you still searching? ;-) +1 if you have documentation on this

Answer (score 4):

You should also be aware that increasing the worker processes creates a web garden.  All worker processes have their own copy of application state, in-process session state, caches, and static data.

Comment: +1: user655459: so what is the side effect of using web garden?